# How to update each row in table with random row from another table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am doing some testing and need to populate `Employee.DepartmentId` with `Id` column from `Department` table.

When I do like this, All rows in `Employee` table have same `DepartmentId` value. But I want different `DepartmentId` values, it is ok if there are some duplicates.

`UPDATE Employee SET DepartmentId = (SELECT Id FROM Department ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1);`

How can I do this?

**Adding more details**:

How can I write SQL query so that for each row in `Employee`, engine goes and fetches a random row from `Department` table, rather than fetch one random row from `Department` table and use that for every row in `Employee`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem of over-active optimizers which decide to run the subquery only once.

One solution is to add a correlation clause to the outer query:

```
UPDATE Employee
    SET DepartmentId = (SELECT d.Id
                        FROM Department d
                        WHERE employee.id is not null
                        ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
                       );
```

This gets around the optimizer.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e74c8ec13a99e627f311fb61c2195cd9) is a db<>fiddle.